# CardView: image's corners is not rounded in Android 4.3?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-cardview, cardview

Android Studio version: 2.3.3, Android 4.3

I am using CardView and want to round image's corners.

**Layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/card_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_width"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/img_lights" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can ses I set

`card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp`

**Here is the result:**

[image: Not round image]

But image's corners is not rounded. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 3):

**Please Try this Class for Image Round corner**

```
public class RoundedCornerImageLayout extends FrameLayout {
private final static float CORNER_RADIUS = 30.0f;
private float cornerRadius;

public RoundedCornerImageLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null, 0);
}

public RoundedCornerImageLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs, 0);
}

public RoundedCornerImageLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}


@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int count = canvas.save();

    final Path path = new Path();
    path.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.INTERSECT);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restoreToCount(count);
 }
}
```

**In Xml**

```
<com.utils.RoundedCornerImageLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_5">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/scout_report_color"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
                </com.utils.RoundedCornerImageLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setUseCompatPadding(boolean)) of `cardUseCompatPadding` attribute:

> **CardView** adds additional padding to draw shadows on platforms before Lollipop.
>
> This may cause Cards to have different sizes between Lollipop and before Lollipop. If you need to align **CardView** with other **Views**, you may need api version specific dimension resources to account for the changes. As an alternative, you can set this flag to true and **CardView** will add the same padding values on platforms Lollipop and after..

Apply `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` to your `CardView`.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I answered the same here below. But I am suprised he said it does not work and he downvoted it! How is it not working to him? @azizbekian

Answer (score 1):

Add to `app`

To be

```
app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Then import necessary values!

Comment: Not help: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"      app:cardCornerRadius="15dp`

Comment: I found the problem. This is because I start on Android 4.3. If I start on Android 6.0 - then all is ok.

Comment: I have found your thing add that on the layout. I have edited the answer. Also consider upvoting if it works!

Comment: Unfortunately not help. Work only on Android 5.0+

Answer (score 1):

The padding you see is the result of support for older than API 20. To make your layouts look the same either on the **pre-Lollipop** (and pre-`CardView` widget) or **Lollipop and newer**, Android introduced some additional attributes.

Because overlapping the content - rounding the corners - was difficult for older Android versions, the [`cardPreventCornerOverlap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardPreventCornerOverlap) has been added and has been set by default as `true`. That is why there're white stripes around your image.

To remove this padding *turn off* **cardPreventCornerOverlap**. You can do it:

- **via xml** by `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`
- or **programatically** by `yourCardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false)`.

Keep in mind that this gives you the effect you want only for API 20+. 
On devices with older versions of system, your rounded corners will be invisible (hidden under not-rounded image).

To know more check [the CardView doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html). In the first paragraph you can find the official note about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following drawable as background of your image.

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     android:background="drawable/rounded"
     android:src="@drawable/img_lights" />
```

**drawable/rounded.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
  <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: I known that by "shape" I can do this. But I want do this only by CardView element.